# How to set selected value into p:selectOneMenu?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have `p:selectOneMenu`:

```
        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="categoryList" filter="true"
                    id="parentCategoryList" style="width: 200px" effect="fade"
                    panelStyleClass="categoryListPanel"
                    converter="#{categoryConverter}" widgetVar="categoryListWV"
                    value="#{categoryService.category}">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="@this" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No parent" />
                    <f:selectItems var="currCateg"
                        value="#{categoryService.categories}"
                        itemLabel="#{currCateg.name}" itemValue="#{currCateg}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to set value via javascript. In the web I found this solution:

```
widgetVar.selectValue(value);
```

I apply it to my case:

```js
function addNewSubCategory() {
 var div = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-state-highlight")[0];
 var label = div.getElementsByTagName("label")[0];
 var parent = label.innerHTML;//name of item, String 
 if (parent === 'Shop')
  return;
 categoryListWV.selectValue(parent);//invoked, but does not set value
 alert(categoryListWV.getSelectedValue());//works correct
 alert(categoryListWV.getSelectedLabel());//works correct
 openAddCategBtn();//open dialog where p:selectOneMenu located
}
```

**PS** Items in `p:selectOneMenu` are objects. I wrote converter for them

Comment: Does `parent` variable match with an **`itemValue`** of `categoryListWV` select?

Comment: @Miguel, `parent` is a String, `itemValue` is an object called `CategoryEntity`. I think that it can be a problem too. I tried to set into `selectValue()` method CategoryEntity.toString() string (I thought that then converter will be invoked, but it does not). I do not know how to pass into `selectValue(var)` java object from server.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. Thinking in an alternative solution for your problem I understand that your `selectOneMenu` depends on *"something"* which calls to `addNewSubCategory` function. Can this *"something"* call an `actionListener` method from the Bean? Inside this method you would be able to change the object `categoryService.category` (backend object of selecOneMenu). If you can do that, you only have to `update` the selectOneMenu when actionListener finishes.